# In the MV* design pattern, is a model a single unit of data or all the logic that works with the data?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mvvm, mv

I have been trying to familiarize myself with this pattern, but I am not sure I am grasping the concept of the "Model" correctly.

For example, would a single cell in an array constitute one "Model" unit, or would the actual array and all logic for get/set on that array constitute one "Model" unit?

Comment: Whatever makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model is all data, logic, and rules. So the actual array and all logic for get/set constitutes the model. There is no explicit sub-model unit per se in the MV design pattern.

Comment: Does this vary by framework? In backbone.js for example, it would seem each individual piece of data is considered a model, while the whole model set is considered a collection. In that regard, would this mean the design pattern is not strict on what constitutes each component?

Comment: That's right. How the pattern subdivides into further abstract subunits is neither a standard nor an imposed specification.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me understand backbone a bit better. I was having trouble because I thought the pattern was strict in what constitutes each component.